# writing a test to check the file returned by a ring response

Tags: clojure

I have a compojure route which returns a file. I want to test -

1) If a file is returned. 
2) The specific file that was returned.

When I run `(app (ring.mock/request :get "/myroute"))` I get

`{:body #<File resources/public/templates/index.html>, :headers {"Content-Length" "2349", "Last-Modified" "Sat, 16 Mar 2013 11:01:03 GMT"}, :status 200}`

How do I check that the returned value in the body is of a type file ? And getting more ambitious can I check it is the file located at 'resources/public/templates/index.html' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ring requests are just maps, so you can extract the body with the :body keyword and then check it's type with `type`

```
(type (:body (app (ring.mock/request :get "/myroute"))))
```

(perhaps I'm not understanding the question though?)

Comment: That is what I was looking for, how do I get the type of the file and as you mentioned the function 'type' does it !